# Prove for all $ n\in \mathbb{N} $ ,$n ≥ 1, a(n)$ is odd.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Prove for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\backslash \{0\}$, $a(n)$ is odd.

Consider the sequence defined as followed:

$a(1)= 1$

$a(2)= 3$,where $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$a(n)=a(n-2)+2a(n-1), n ≥3$$
Conjecture:

> $a(3) = 1+2(3) = 7$
>
> $a(4)= 3+2(1+2(3))= 17$
>
> $a(5)= 7+2(3+2(1+2(3)))=41$

I am unable to see a pattern in the above sequence to conjecture a formula to prove it by induction. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Recommend a proof via strong induction.  In proving that $a(n)$ is odd, recognize that due to induction hypothesis $a(n-2)$ is odd and so $a(n)$ is the sum of an odd number $a(n-2)$ and an even number $2a(n-1)$ and is therefore odd.  You need two base cases (which are given in the problem statement already).

Comment: i'm not the greatest expert, but shouldn't it be $a_n$ ect? (i left it as it is, cuz unsure)

Comment: @saturatedexpo both notations are used.  In the case that the notation used is well enough understood, it is often best to leave it in the same notation used by the OP if possible.

Comment: @saturatedexpo A sequence can be defined as a function whose domain is a subset of integers, hence the functional notation.

Comment: The induction assumes a() is odd.  One of n-1 and n-2 is even and the other is odd.  So you have an odd times an even plus an odd times an odd.  That's an odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easier method: proof via strong induction.

Base cases: $a(1)=1$ and $a(2)=3$ are both odd.

Induction hypothesis: **All** values of $a(k)$ for $1\leq k\leq n$ are odd for some $n$

We wish to show that this implies that $a(n+1)$ is also odd.

Indeed, since $a(n+1)=2a(n)+a(n-1)$, and $a(n-1)$ is odd by the induction hypothesis, we have $a(n-1)=2m+1$ for some $m\in \Bbb Z$ and therefore $a(n+1)=2(a(n)+m)+1$ is odd.

Thus, $a(n)$ is odd for all $n\geq 1$

---

Overkill method: actually coming up with a closed form expression for $a(n)$

Given the recurrence $a(n)=2a(n-1)+a(n-2)$, we look at the characteristic polynomial: $x^2-2x-1$

This factors as $(x-1-\sqrt{2})(x-1+\sqrt{2})$, implying that $a(n)=c_1 (1-\sqrt{2})^n+c_2 (1+\sqrt{2})^n$ for some values of $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Using the initial conditions, $a(1)=1$ and $a(2)=3$, we find $c_1=c_2=\frac{1}{2}$

That is to say

$$a(n)=\frac{1}{2}\left((1-\sqrt{2})^n+(1+\sqrt{2})^n\right)$$

Applying the binomial theorem:

$a(n)=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \binom{n}{i}[(-\sqrt{2})^i+(\sqrt{2})^i]=\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \binom{n}{2i}[2\cdot 2^i]$

When $i$ is odd, the terms cancel out.  When $i$ is even and at least $2$, the terms will add and be divisible by $4$ and thus still even after dividing by two.  When $i$ is zero, the entry is $2$, which divided by two is one.

Thus, $a(n)=\frac{1}{2}(2+4(k))=1+2k$ for some $k$ and is therefore odd.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:-**$$a(n)-a(n-1)\equiv 0\pmod{2}$$Can you do the proof from here using Mathematical Induction?

Answer (score 2):

As a serious hint: you constantly add a odd number to an even one(*cough* 2a). Now just induct your way through it!

Answer (score 1):

By computation,
$a(n)$ is odd for
$1 \le n \le 5$.

Suppose there is an $n$
such that
$a(n)$ is even.

Let $m$
be the smallest value of $n$
such that
$a(n)$ is even.
Then
$m \ge 6$.

Then
$a(m-2)
=a(m)-2a(m-1)
$
is also even.
This contradicts the assumption
that $m$ is
the smallest such value.

Therefore
there is no $m$
such that
$a(m)$ is even,
so all $a(n)$ are odd.